# As a high school student, what resources are there to learn discrete mathematics?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am currently taking AP Calculus AB in high school, but I am very interested in computer science and mathematics as a whole. I understand that discrete math and computer science are very closely related. Although I am in high school and there is currently no discrete math offered at my school, I would still like to learn some before going into a college setting. Are there any books, PDFs, or other resources I could use to learn the basics or an introduction to discrete mathematics?

Comment: _Aspects of Combinatorics_, Victor Byrant, is a fun, gentle, broad introduction to combinatorics and graph theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankly, I think the most popular textbooks, Johsonbaugh, Rosen, and Epps are wretched.  They make a vibrant subject dull as dishwater.  Grimaldi is a better book, though some students find it harder, I gather. Frankly, the best intro to discrete math I've ever seen is what I think was the first textbook on the subject, "Finite Mathematical Structures," by Kemeney, Snell and Thompson.  At this moment, there's a [cheap copy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000P9ATHA) on amazon.  You might give it a try.

Apart from that, look at the resources on the Art of Problem Solving website.

Comment: I recall "Finite Mathematics" by K, S, & T. Likely the same book. Delightful stuff.

Comment: I will definitely look into these, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

One combinatorics book aimed at high-school students is *Mathematics of Choice: Or, How to Count Without Counting* by Ivan Niven.  It's well-written and interesting, with a good choice of topics, and the only prerequisite is high-school algebra.  Unfortunately, today Amazon wants \$48 for a used copy and \$118 for new, when the book was originally priced at \$22.  Maybe you can find a more reasonably priced copy somewhere else.